# LayeredDrawable - Set of item during runtime sets it to white

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to set the background of a layer-list during runtime with a fetched image.

I've use code like that to set the drawable within the layer-list with the fetched drawable:

```
    ImageView vw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgVw);
    LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable)vw.getDrawable();               
    BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.title_bg));
    drawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.imgUserPic, d);
    vw.postInvalidate();
```

If I use the code like that the image within the layerdrawable turns white.

But if I set a second image view with the drawable d it works just fine:

```
    ImageView vw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgVw);
    ImageView vw2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgVw2);
    LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable)vw.getDrawable();               
    BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.title_bg));
    vw2.setImageDrawable(d);
    drawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.imgUserPic, d);
```